# Google Code SVN using AnkhSVN to VS2010 Project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn

im using VS2010... my project is saved under SVN in Google code.

how do i install the project on my VS2010 for continues work with SVN access?

my pc was formatted so everything was removed.

Answer (score 0):

Using AnkhSVN:

1. Start Visual Studio,
2. Go to File | Open | Subversion project,
3. Enter your project's URL and manually locate its sln or *prj file, click Open,
4. Click OK.

Using VisualSVN:

1. Start Visual Studio,
2. Go to VisualSVN | Get Solution from Subversion,
3. As Repository URL enter your projects URL and click OK.